# Does Shockbolts lower the target's resistances?

Tags: torchlight-2

I'm confused about the skill "Staff Mastery" in Torchlight 2. I'm pretty sure I'm right, but let me just get this straight:

If I use Shockbolts, (in addition to the other skills),

- Does lower the target's resistances?
- Does it also lower them if I hit the target with my staff?

Also,

- Am I **required** to wield a staff for this to have effect?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the skill Staff Mastery, you can lower the elemental armor of any enemy by hitting them with:

- Your staff
- Magma Spear
- Magma Mace
- Icy Blast
- Shockbolts

The passive skill Staff Mastery *ONLY* works when you have a staff equipped. This is a *cumulative* effect and I believe does not go below 100% reduction.